# Embed Python 3 Tkinter module as Widget in PyQT5

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyqt5

First post and new to python so apologies if the post formatting is weird or the coding errors are dumb.

I created a module using tkinter that I want to embed into a pyQt5 MainWindow widget.

This is the tkinter module, titled Del.py, I'm trying to import.

```
class Delfiles(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.mw = self.mainwindow()

    def mainwindow(self):
        # mainwindow formatting

    def dellist(self):
        # delete function for buttons in mainwindow


class Results(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
    # toplevel popup that appears after dellist function runs

# root = Delfiles()
# root.mainloop()
```

This is the part of the pyqt5 module where I've been trying to embed the tkinter module into.

```
class SpreadSheet(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, parent=None):
        super(SpreadSheet, self).__init__(parent)
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.cells = {}

        self.create_table1()
        self.create_table2()
        deletefiles = Del.mw()
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()

        self.vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.table1)
        self.vlayout.addWidget(self.table2)
        self.hlayout.addLayout(self.vlayout)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(deletefiles)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.hlayout)

        self.table1.cellDoubleClicked.connect(self.celldoubleclicked)
        self.table2.installEventFilter(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()

if __name__ == __main__:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    sheet = SpreadSheet(5, 5)
    sheet.resize(1500, 900)
    sheet.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# https://negfeedback.blogspot.com/2017/12/a-simple-gui-spreadsheet-in-less-than.html
#link to source code for the pyqt5 module I'm working with
```

Every time I try to run the pyqt module with the tkinter module embedded, the tkinter module either opens on top of the pyqt5 module or i get the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
AttributeError: module 'Del' has no attribute 'mw'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do not combine 2 libraries that serve the same, why do you want to use tkinter? What feature does tkinter have that does not have PyQt5 ?. In particular you cannot combine 2 GUI libraries because they need an event loop (app.exec_() and root.mainloop() in the case of PyQt5 and Tkinter, respectively) to work, but if you use both they will be blocked.

Comment: The Del.py module was the first code I wrote and I just randomly ended up using tkinter.  I found the pyqt5 module online that helped me with another issue and was trying to modify that code to also include the functionality of the Del.py code.  I only wanted to try importing the Del methods to avoid having to "reinvent the wheel" in pyqt5, not because I feel I have to use tk.  But if it's better to recreate the methods in pyqt5 so as not to mix libraries, I guess I'll just have to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, that's what you'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create windows in tkinter and use them in a PyQT5 application. Each GUI toolkit has a rendering model that knows nothing about the other.